# Dynamic locator: update to new position inside `Manipluate`

Tags: manipulate, dynamic, locator

I'd like the locator to update to its new position when `k` is altered:

```
Manipulate[ Graphics[{}, PlotRange -> 2, Frame -> True], 
{{c, If[k == 0, {0, 0}, If[k == 1, {0, 1}, {0, 2}]]}, Locator, 
Appearance -> Graphics[{Disk[{0, 0}]}, ImageSize -> 10]}, 
{{k, 0}, {0, 1, 2}}]
```

Have tried with `Dynamic`, but failing abysmally. Could someone please point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 4):

### Example

**Code**

```
DynamicModule[
 {k = 0},
 Column[{
   (*Control*)
   SetterBar[Dynamic @ k, {0, 1}],
   (*Visual*)
   Dynamic @ Graphics[
     Switch[k,
      0,  Locator[{0, 0}],
      1, Locator[{0, 1}]],
     (*Graphics Options*)
     Axes -> True,
     PlotRange -> 2
     ]
   },
  (*Column Options*)
  Alignment -> Center]
 ]
```

**Output**

[image: output example]

Comment: Wonderful - thanks very much

Answer (score 4):

Body of `Manipulate` is effectively wrapped with `Dynamic` so we can just put it there:

```
Manipulate[
 c = If[k == 0, {0, 0}, If[k == 1, {0, 1}, {0, 2}]];

 Graphics[{}, PlotRange -> 2, Frame -> True], 

 {{c, {0, 0}}, Locator, Appearance -> Graphics[{Disk[{0, 0}]}, ImageSize -> 10]}, 
 {{k,    0}, {0, 1, 2}}]
```

Comment: great - thank you - so simple! :)